# Why I can no longer drag and drop files into firefox?

Tags: firefox

I need to know about firefox. Usually, I am able to drag and drop pictures file to say web.whatsapp, or even superuser.com

That allows me to upload files quickly.

I can no longer do that.

Now, I cannot do that. I search the web. There are articles on why people cannot drag and drop from firefox. There is no article why people cannot drag and drop **to** firefox.

I have UAC enabled to always notify. So that's not an issue at all.

Comment: You could try uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox. Save your bookmarks first (or even the entire profile folder).

Comment: Please describe in as much detail as possible what happens when you try to drag an image to the answer editor right here.

Answer (score 0):

> I have UAC enabled to always notify. So that's not an issue at all.

UAC might be exactly the issue. (Not your specific setting, but how UAC works in general.)

Programs running as "elevated" through UAC have a higher "integrity level", which prevents lower-integrity programs from tampering with higher-integrity ones (e.g. sending spoofed keyboard input into a Command Prompt window).

This includes drag & drop – you cannot drag anything from a lower-integrity app into a higher-integrity one, and because Windows Explorer *never* runs elevated, this means you can never drag any files from it into an UAC elevated app. (However, you can still drag & drop stuff from other elevated apps, such as third-party file managers.)

So make sure you've started Firefox from the Windows Start menu or similar, *not* from any elevated app, and that UAC was already enabled at that time.